# Create candle data from tick data using Apache Spark Stream in java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

We are getting tick data on Kafka which we are streaming to Apache Spark. We need to create candle data from that stream data.

First option i thought to create dataframe and from there run sql queries like

```
SELECT t1.price AS open,
       m.high,
       m.low,
       t2.price as close,
       open_time
FROM (SELECT MIN(timeInMilliseconds) AS min_time,
             MAX(timeInMilliseconds) AS max_time,
             MIN(price) as low,
             MAX(price) as high,
             FLOOR(timeInMilliseconds/(1000*60)) as open_time
      FROM ticks
      GROUP BY open_time) m
JOIN ticks t1 ON t1.timeInMilliseconds = min_time
JOIN ticks t2 ON t2.timeInMilliseconds = max_time
```

But i am not sure would that be able to get data for old ticks

is it possible to use some methods of Spark library to create similar to this ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducable example. Such things are better expressed in data rather than words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a look at Window Operations on Event Time https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time
That is exactly what you need.  Here is a scatch code

```
val windowedCounts = tickStream.groupBy(
   window($"timeInMilliseconds", "1 minutes"))
 ).agg(
    first("price").alias("open"),
    min("price").alias("min"),
    max ("price").alias("max"),
    last("price").alias("close"))
```